# How to rotate a scope environment around a single point?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to rotate a figure around a single point B by an angle of 20°. To do so, I tried to use the scope environment (`\begin{scope}[rotate around={20:(B)}] ... \end{scope}`) but apparently I can only get the axis to rotate. The rest of the figure stays still. What am I forgetting here?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.325, decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[line width = 2pt]{latex}}}]

    % Variables
    \def\alphaa{0.3}
    \def\R{15}
    
    \def\x{-\alphaa*\R}
    \def\xx{(1-\alphaa)*\R}
    \def\xxx{\alphaa*\R}
    \def\y{0}
    \def\yy{0}
    \def\yyy{1/2*\R}
    
    
    \def\coefx{(\yyy-\y)/(\xxx-\x)}
    \def\ordx{\R/4}
    
    \def\coefxx{(\yyy)/(\xxx)}
    \def\ordxx{0}
    
    \def\coefxxx{(\yy-\yyy)/(\xx-\xxx)}
    \def\ordxxx{\R/2*(1+\alphaa*\R/((1-2*\alphaa)*\R))}
    
    
    % Coordinates
    \coordinate (L1) at ({\R*(1-(\alphaa/3)^(1/3))},0);
    \coordinate (L2) at ({\R*(1+(\alphaa/3)^(1/3))},0);
    \coordinate (L3) at ({-\R*(1+5/12*\alphaa)},0);
    \coordinate (L4) at ({\R*(1/2*(1-2*\alphaa))},{\R*sqrt(3)/2});
    \coordinate (L5) at ({\R*1/2*(1-2*\alphaa)},{-\R*sqrt(3)/2});
    \coordinate (C1) at ({\x},{\y});
    \node[above left] at ({-\alphaa*\R-0.5},0.5) {\large $C_1$};
    \coordinate (C2) at ({\xx},{\yy});
    \node[above right] at ({(1-\alphaa)*\R+0.1},0.1) {\large $C_2$};
    \coordinate (C3) at ({\xxx},{\yyy});
    \node[above left] at (C3) {\large $P$};
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
    \node[above left] at (B) {\large $B$};
    
    \begin{scope}[rotate around={20:(B)}]
        % Axis
        \draw [thick, -latex, line width = 1pt, dashed] ({-\alphaa*\R-\alphaa*\R/2},0)--({\alphaa*\R/2+(1-\alphaa)*\R},0) node[below right] {\large $x$}; %x axis
        \draw [thick, -latex, line width = 1pt, dashed] (0,{-\alphaa*\R/2})--(0,{\R*1/2}) node[above left] {\large $y$}; %y axis
        
        % Celestial bodies
        \draw [thick, fill=yellow] (C1) circle (1); %C1
        \draw [thick, fill=cyan] (C2) circle (0.5); %C2
        \draw [thick, fill=gray] (C3) circle (0.25); %C3
        
        % Lengths
        \draw [thick, |<->|, line width = 1pt] ({-\alphaa*\R},{-\alphaa*\R/2})--({(1-\alphaa)*\R},{-\alphaa*\R/2}) node[midway, below] {$R=\left\|\overrightarrow{r_2}-\overrightarrow{r_1}\right\|$};
        
        \draw [thick, dashed] ({-\alphaa*\R},{-\alphaa*\R/2})--({-\alphaa*\R},0);
        \draw [thick, dashed] ({(1-\alphaa)*\R},{-\alphaa*\R/2})--({(1-\alphaa)*\R},0);
        
        
        % Vectors
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (C1)--(C3)node[midway, above left] {\large $\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r_1}$};
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (B)--(C3)
        node[midway,below right] {\large $\overrightarrow{r_3}=\overrightarrow{r}$};
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (C2)--(C3) node[midway, above right] {\large $\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r_2}$};
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (B)--(C1) node[midway, below] {\large $\overrightarrow{r_1}$};
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (B)--(C2) node[midway, below] {\large $\overrightarrow{r_2}$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Shift -> rotate -> shift back. IIRC there is something called `rotate around = (x, y)` but that's the same idea.

Comment: Shifting works, but when I use either `rotate` or `rotate around`, the code only rotates the axis for some reason.

Comment: Do you want all the picture to be rotated? If so, your `scope` is misplaced. And if you want to rotate all the text nodes, you have to add `transform shape` in the scope declaration.

Comment: @SebGlav Adding `transform shape` to all of the nodes and moving `\begin{scope}[rotate around={20:(B)}]` above the `% Coordinates` section did the trick (although the fontsize decreased a lot). If you want to publish the answer I will validate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so here's what worked for me (even if there are some adjustments to make). You don't have to add `transform shape` to every node individually, but only in the `tikzpicture` declaration (and you don't need a `scope` anymore):

[image: rotate around a point]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75,transform shape, rotate around={20:(0,0)}, decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 0.5 with {\arrow[line width = 2pt]{latex}}}]

        % Variables
        \def\alphaa{0.3}
        \def\R{15}
        
        \def\x{-\alphaa*\R}
        \def\xx{(1-\alphaa)*\R}
        \def\xxx{\alphaa*\R}
        \def\y{0}
        \def\yy{0}
        \def\yyy{1/2*\R}
        
        
        \def\coefx{(\yyy-\y)/(\xxx-\x)}
        \def\ordx{\R/4}
        
        \def\coefxx{(\yyy)/(\xxx)}
        \def\ordxx{0}
        
        \def\coefxxx{(\yy-\yyy)/(\xx-\xxx)}
        \def\ordxxx{\R/2*(1+\alphaa*\R/((1-2*\alphaa)*\R))}
        \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
        
        % Coordinates
        \coordinate (L1) at ({\R*(1-(\alphaa/3)^(1/3))},0);
        \coordinate (L2) at ({\R*(1+(\alphaa/3)^(1/3))},0);
        \coordinate (L3) at ({-\R*(1+5/12*\alphaa)},0);
        \coordinate (L4) at ({\R*(1/2*(1-2*\alphaa))},{\R*sqrt(3)/2});
        \coordinate (L5) at ({\R*1/2*(1-2*\alphaa)},{-\R*sqrt(3)/2});
        \coordinate (C1) at ({\x},{\y});
        \node[above left] at ({-\alphaa*\R-0.5},0.5) {\large $C_1$};
        \coordinate (C2) at ({\xx},{\yy});
        \node[above right] at ({(1-\alphaa)*\R+0.1},0.1) {\large $C_2$};
        \coordinate (C3) at ({\xxx},{\yyy});
        \node[above left] at (C3) {\large $P$};
        
        \node[above left] at (B) {\large $B$};
    
    
        % Axis
        \draw [thick, -latex, line width = 1pt, dashed] ({-\alphaa*\R-\alphaa*\R/2},0)--({\alphaa*\R/2+(1-\alphaa)*\R},0) node[below right] {\large $x$}; %x axis
        \draw [thick, -latex, line width = 1pt, dashed] (0,{-\alphaa*\R/2})--(0,{\R*1/2}) node[above left] {\large $y$}; %y axis
        
        % Celestial bodies
        \draw [thick, fill=yellow] (C1) circle (1); %C1
        \draw [thick, fill=cyan] (C2) circle (0.5); %C2
        \draw [thick, fill=gray] (C3) circle (0.25); %C3
        
        % Lengths
        \draw [thick, |<->|, line width = 1pt] ({-\alphaa*\R},{-\alphaa*\R/2})--({(1-\alphaa)*\R},{-\alphaa*\R/2}) node[midway, below] {$R=\left\|\overrightarrow{r_2}-\overrightarrow{r_1}\right\|$};
        
        \draw [thick, dashed] ({-\alphaa*\R},{-\alphaa*\R/2})--({-\alphaa*\R},0);
        \draw [thick, dashed] ({(1-\alphaa)*\R},{-\alphaa*\R/2})--({(1-\alphaa)*\R},0);
        
        
        % Vectors
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (C1)--(C3)node[midway, above left] {\large $\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r_1}$};
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (B)--(C3)
        node[midway,below right] {\large $\overrightarrow{r_3}=\overrightarrow{r}$};
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (C2)--(C3) node[midway, above right] {\large $\overrightarrow{r}-\overrightarrow{r_2}$};
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (B)--(C1) node[midway, below] {\large $\overrightarrow{r_1}$};
        \draw [thick, postaction={decorate}, line width = 1pt] (B)--(C2) node[midway, below] {\large $\overrightarrow{r_2}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And yes, if you keep your scaling factor that low, the text is reaaly small. So I found it better to scale a bit less. You could adjust some things like the text size and the circle size also.